# Are the prizes we win from buying things halal?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

We buy so many things daily which offer you prizes, such as Lays crisps.

[image: Lays promtion]

For example, I might buy a biscuit, which promotes offers like: **if you find a paper with a code inside your biscuit packet, you will win $1000**

If I find the paper inside and win a prize, and I don't give money for prize and earn them, is it interest?  Are these prizes halal or haram?

Comment: Do you mean that you like buy candy boxes, which promotes offers like; "if you find a paper with a code inside your candy box, you will win 10 000 Dollar"? Are we talking about buying 100 candy boxes or like 1 - 2, in order to enjoy the candy and ALSO as a bonus, win?

Comment: @Kilise If you remove your second question , it is perfect.

Comment: Okay! But just to make it clear, when buying these candy boxes, is the *intention* to eat candy (1), or to win (2) ? or both (3)?

Comment: In order to answer we still need to know the intention of the purchase. As I asked in the above comment.

Comment: @Kilise both...

Answer (score 1):

Gambling is haram, so the question is: *Is this gambling?*  Ordinarily, the answer is no.

The key distinction is the lack of entry fee, without which scholars consider it halal:

> ... if entry into the prize-draw is free and no money is demanded, then that would not constitute gambling, hence permitted.
> <sub>[Darul Iftaa](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/6166)</sub>
>
> If a sweepstakes is merely promotional where no purchase is necessary, then it is like a prize or award that the business volunteers to advertise its products and to attract more customers. Such sweepstakes are permissible in Islam.
> <sub>[IslamAwareness.net](http://www.islamawareness.net/Gambling/gambling_fatwa004.html)</sub>

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/45854) say that there is nothing wrong with that provided (a) the price is not raised for the competition and (b) the purchaser does not buy the product solely for the sake of entering the competition.