# Investing in Etfs from revolut, halal or haram?

Tags: investment

Salam people

Many thanks in advance. I was wondering if i can invest in a technology ETF 2B76 constituted by techonology comçanies which do not involve haram activities. Do you think i can invest? Is it halal? If not which platform or etfs can i invest? Is revolut halal?

Many thanks,

Comment: I am a westerner, and only slowly learning about the Quran. What I know about ETFs is that they are not based on real values and so are a kind of bet or gambling. I, myself wouldn't do it, not out of religious reasons but plainly because I won't buy hot air. I am really interested in an good answer based on Quran views.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the subject and make me find https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12451/55518 in my opinion a very good explanation of what haram gambling is as opposed to taking a calculated risk, such as having a caravan transport goods through deserts and risk of robbery.

Comment: If you have enough money, you can invest in stocks on the stock market. Buying, say, shares of McDonalds or whatever, checking if each of it is halal for you. Banks usually charge you for having an account, and usually there is a minimum charge. So if you have but one share of McDonalds in your deposit, worth about 200$, they will charge you the same amount as if it be worth 5000$, depending on the bank. The alternative is to by investment funds. The backdraw is that they charge money when you buy, and every year as administration fees. Pick carefully.