# Is gambling allowed when there is only fun but no property or other values on risk?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

The title says it all: is gambling allowed when there is only fun but no property or other values on risk?

In view of https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12451/55518 it looks like, when the stakes at hand are zero, and nothing is to be gained but a laugh, this should be allowed.

Is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "only fun but no property"? Are you still paying for this experience, and simply getting nothing else in return?

Comment: @goldPseudo I don't understand your question. What I was referring to is some kids throwing dices, and get excited on who has the most eyes. Nothing payed for, no money gained or lost.

Comment: @goldPseudo to make another example: paying the piper to play a random tune of his own choice, that would not look like gambling to me.